# Django-Haystack - How to use Haystack with django-comments?

Tags: django-haystack

I'm struggling with Django-Haystack.

I need to do an Index that have Articles and Comment articles. My doubt is how can I put in a document based index the Articles and the Comments.

How can I search for keywords in the comments and in the articles and output the article with that keywords(article comments, article)?

It is possible?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is forget the notion that a `SearchIndex` must correspond exactly to a model. It's only sourced from one.

The simplest way to do this would be to add the comments to the indexed document using a template. This presume your `Article` model as a `title` field:

```
class ArticleIndex(SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Article
```

Note the keyword argument `use_template` is set to true. The default value for this is [search/indexes/{app_label}/{model_name}_{field_name}.txt](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html?highlight=use_template#template-name). In that template just output the content you want to index. E.g.

```
{{ object.title|safe }}

{{ object.body|safe }}

{% for comment in object.comments.all %}
{{ comment|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

While I'm afraid the specific reverse relation name here is probably wrong, that's the gist of what you want to do. Again, this is a simple way of accomplishing what you've specifically stated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

In your `models.py`, presuming comments are attached to an `Article`, you want a method that returns comments attached to it (there is no easy way to do this):

```
class Article:
    def comments(self):
        ids = [self.id]
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Article)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=ctype,
                                          object_pk__in=ids,
                                          is_removed=False)
        return comments
```

In your `search_indexes.py`, make sure the `ArticleIndex` has `use_template=True`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

class ArticleIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(use_template=True)
```

In your index template, e.g. [templates/search/indexes/article_text.txt](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html?highlight=use_template#template-name):

```
{% for comment in object.comments.all %}
    {{ comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, the only remaining problem is to update that specific index object when a comment is added or removed. Here we use signals:

In your models.py:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from haystack import site
from django.contrib.comments.signals import (comment_was_posted,
                                             comment_was_flagged)

@receiver(comment_was_posted)
def comment_posted(sender, **kwargs):
    site.get_index(Article).update_object(kwargs['comment'].content_object)


@receiver(comment_was_flagged)
def comment_flagged(sender, **kwargs):
    site.get_index(Article).update_object(kwargs['comment'].content_object)
```

Comment: This apparently no longer works. In current version of haystack, >>> from haystack import site
Traceback:ImportError: cannot import name 'site'